# Use different output.libraryTarget for a Web Worker

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker, webpack-5

I have this Webpack configuration:

```
{
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "system",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to use a Web Worker. I'm using the [standard Webpack 5 syntax](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/):

```
new Worker(new URL('./MyWorker', import.meta.url));
```

Now Webpack outputs the Web Worker as a System.js module. How can I change it to something different, like ES module, without affecting the main bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chunkFormat` to specify what the chunk formats are, workers are by default `array-push`, https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputchunkformat.

You can also create multiple configs with different targets for different entries.

```
const config = {
  //
}

module.exports = (env) => {
  if (env.module) {
    config.entry = //path/to/index
    config.output.libraryTarget = 'module'
  } else {
    config.entry = //path/to/worker
    config.output.libraryTarget = 'umd'
  }

  return config
}
```

Then you can separately compile your web workers or chunks different from others.  You can also use `chunkFileName: () =>` along with that.

If you want to compile it in a single run, without having to run it twice using different configs, you can also manually invoke the webpack compiler with both configs.

```
import {Compiler} from 'webpack'
// or import webpack from 'webpack'

compiler.run(config)
compiler.run(config2)
```

Then you can run both of them at the same time and compile everything.

Another possible option is `enabledChunkLoadingTypes`, https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenabledchunkloadingtypes, which will allow you to specify the available loading types for chunks which webpack will automatically use based on the entry function.  I've never used that myself so I don't know if that'll work but it's something you can try.

Comment: `chunkFormat` and `enabledChunkLoadingTypes` didn't work for me. As for multiple configurations, I'm already using this workaround, but I was hoping for a simpler solution.